# Language formed by adding symbols to start or end turn by turn

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, formal-languages

A word is formed by starting with "$0$" and then adding "$1$" either to the start or to the end i.e we can form "$10$" or "$01$". In the next step we add a "$0$", again either to the start or to the end. This is continued, alternating the symbol we add.

Denote by  $L_n$ the language containing all words of length $n$ that can be formed like this. We can define this recursively:

$$L_0 = \{""\}$$
$$L_n = \{c+w \space | \space w\in L_{n-1}\} \cup \{ w+c \space | \space w\in L_{n-1} \},$$
$$ \text{where } c="0" \text{ if } n \text{ is odd and }  c="1" \text{ if } n \text{ is even }$$
$$\text{and + means the concatenation of strings.}$$

We get:

> $L_0 = [""]$ (the empty string)
>   $L_1 = ["0"]$
>   $L_2 = ["10", "01"]$
>   $L_3 = ["010", "100", "001"]$
>   $L_4 = ["1010", "0101", "1100", "1001", "0011"]$
>   $L_5 = ["01010", "10100", "00101", "01100", "11000", "01001", "10010", "00011", "00110"]$
>   $L_6 = ["101010", "010101", "110100", "101001", "100101", "001011", "101100", "011001", "111000", "110001", "010011", "110010", "100011", "000111", "100110", "001101"]$

Denote $a_n = \# L_n$. These start out as 
$$[1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 9, 16, 29, 52, 94, 170, 308, 560, 1018, 1856, 3383, 6177, 11279, 20614, 37685, 68926, 126112, 230802, 422557, 773730, 1417222, \dots]$$

**Questions:**

- Is there a context free grammar for the language $L=\bigcup L_n$?
- Is there a formula for $a_n$, or what is their generating function?
- I noticed that $\frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}}$ seems to approach something like $1.832...$. Is this true and what is this constant? It's like the factor "how many different words" each word from $L_{n-1}$ produces to $L_n$ (each produces two, but some of these are same as others).

Comment: For the first question: Yes, of course. The process you describe $L$ by directly corresponds to a context-free grammar: $$ A\to \varepsilon \mid 1B \mid B1 \qquad B\to 0A \mid A0 \qquad S \to A \mid B $$

Comment: Assuming your values for $a_n$ are correct, [OEIS doesn't find anything](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C2%2C3%2C5%2C9%2C16%2C29).

Comment: @HenningMakholm I thought about something like that but had and still have some trouble seeing it because "the symbol could end up in the middle". But I'm beginning to believe it : ). Yes I also tried OEIS. Upto $94$ it finds something but not after that. If someone want's to also check the values, we'd have more confirmation.

Comment: The values check out, and the next one is 2596086. A Hankel matrix formed from these first 27 entries has a non-zero determinant. Therefore there is no linear recurrence of order 14 or less.

Comment: We can see the strings as binary numbers, maybe that helps. The Mathematica code to generate $a_n$ becomes: `add[list_, i_] := 
  If[EvenQ[i], Union[list, 2 list], Union[2^i + list, 2 list + 1]];
Length /@ FoldList[add, {0}, Range[30]]`

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the motivation for this question? Is that language an example in some paper or textbook? I'm curious whether the language is inherently ambiguous, in which case finding a closed form for the $a_n$ will be difficult.

Comment: @rici It's not from any book (that I know of). The reason I started to think about this language is a game where two players choose turn by turn from a (finite) sequence of numbers, either the first or the last number, and try to maximize their score.

Answer (score 0):

Numerical experimentation suggests that the generating function has a simple pole at about 0.544938, so that the ratios should go to 1.83507 or so.